# How to invoke a REST service from BPEL in Oracle SOA, with Basic Authentication?

Tags: basic-authentication, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-soa

I am working with the Oracle Fusion Middleware 12.1.3, and I am developing a BPEL process which has to invoke a remote REST service that needs a Basic Authentication.

I created an *External reference* to the Rest Service, and in my `composite.xml`, it looks like this :

```
....
<component name="MyCompositeBASProcess" version="2.0">
    <implementation.bpel src="BPEL/MyCompositeBASProcess.bpel"/>
    <componentType>
        <service name="mycompositebasprocess_client" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/MyCompositeBASProcess.wsdl">
            <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/myPartitionSOA/MyCompositeBAS/MyCompositeBASProcess#wsdl.interface(MyCompositeBASProcess)"
                    callbackInterface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/myPartitionSOA/MyCompositeBAS/MyCompositeBASProcess#wsdl.interface(MyCompositeBASProcessCallback)"/>
        </service>
        <reference name="CMProxyRS" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/CMProxyRS.wsdl">
            <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/myPartitionSOA/MyCompositeBAS/CMProxyRS#wsdl.interface(CMProxyRS_ptt)"/>
        </reference>
    </componentType>
    <property name="bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy" type="xs:string" many="false">async.persist</property>
</component>

<reference name="CMProxyRS" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/CMProxyRS.wsdl">
    <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/myPartitionSOA/MyCompositeBAS/CMProxyRS#wsdl.interface(CMProxyRS_ptt)"/>
    <binding.rest config="Adapters/CMProxyRS.wadl" location="http://server_WITHOUT_basic-auth/cmproxy/resources/v2/" />
</reference>
....
```

With this code I invoke a REST service which is not secured by a BASIC_Auth, and it works fine.

Now, when I switch to a remote environment which needs a basic authentication, I did not manage to succeed.

I found some examples to invoke SOAP services with basic auth, but nothing really interesting for REST services. But, in the Oracle Fusion stack 12.1.3, REST services are "adapted" to SOAP services before being used, so I thought that I could use the examples I found.

So, I updated my `composite.xml` to add the user/password and the policy :

```
....
<reference name="CMProxyRS" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/CMProxyRS.wsdl">
    <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/myPartitionSOA/MyCompositeBAS/CMProxyRS#wsdl.interface(CMProxyRS_ptt)"/>
    <binding.rest config="Adapters/CMProxyRS.wadl" location="http://server_WITH_basic-auth/cmproxy/resources/v2/">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy" orawsp:category="security" orawsp:status="enabled"/>
        <!-- <property name="oracle.webservices.auth.username">weblogic</property>                       -->
        <!-- <property name="oracle.webservices.auth.password">password</property>  -->
        <property name="oracle.webservices.preemptiveBasicAuth">true</property> 
        <property  name="javax.xml.ws.security.auth.username"  many="false"  override="may">weblogic</property>
        <property  name="javax.xml.ws.security.auth.password"  many="false"  override="may">password</property>
    </binding.rest>    
</reference>
....
```

As you can see, I tried with the `javax.xml.ws.security.auth.` properties and with the `oracle.webservices.auth.` properties. But both failed : on the remote, I do not get any Basic Authentication in the requests.

I also updated my `CMProxyRS.wadl` to add the `Authorization` key in the `HTTP Header`. For example :

```
<resources>
  <resource path="/documents">
     <method name="GET" soa:wsdlOperation="searchDocument">
        <request>
           <param name="Authorization" style="header" soa:expression="$msg.request/tns:Authorization" default="" type="xsd:string"/>
           <param name="queryText" style="query" soa:expression="$msg.request/tns:queryText" default="" type="xsd:string"/>
           <param name="fields" style="query" soa:expression="$msg.request/tns:fields" default="id,name,originalName,originalFormat,originalExtension,alternateFormat,alternateExtension,revision" type="xsd:string"/>
           <param name="waitForIndexing" style="query" soa:expression="$msg.request/tns:waitForIndexing" default="false" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </request>
        <response status="200">
....
```

And this `Authorization` was "replicated" in the WSDL.`CMProxyRS.wsdl` :

```
<element name="searchDocument_params">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Authorization" type="string"/>
            <element name="queryText" type="string"/>
            <element name="fields" type="string"/>
            <element name="waitForIndexing" type="boolean"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

This did not help. In fact, I am really not sure that what I added in my `composite.xml` (the properties username, password, preemptiveBasicAuth) is used by the SOA Engine to build the REST request.

(I would like to specify that it is not a user/password issue : when I test this REST query with the same user/password from Postman, it work fine.)

How can I manage to invoke a REST service with basic Authentication from a soa-composite ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send custom HTTP headers in BPEL.

Take a look at this [post](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2012/04/retrieve-or-set-http-header-from-oracle.html). You need to add oracle.webservices.http.headers on the reference service and then you can populate variables and send them on your REST invoke acticity in BPEL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **OWSM** oracle/http_jwt_token_client_policy to pass the required headers in the request.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue initially trying to invoke WADL from Oracle SOA 12c.

It started working after applying the following OWSM security policy:

```
oracle/http_jwt_token_client_policy
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29766346)

Comment: @INDRAJITH: While this would benefit from additional explanation and clarity, it most certainly offers an answer to the question. If it's not useful because of the limited explanation, or if you believe it's wrong, it should be downvoted. It should not be deleted.